# Multi-touch screen and WPF listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, touch

I'm using a cyclotouch screen overlay and need a drag and drop motion (i.e. finger down and move) on a listbox item to behave identically to a mouse drag and drop (i.e. click down, hold finger and move). I'm pretty desperate for help on this - I can see a lot of articles about explaining how to implement a scroll response in a wpf listbox to a touchscreen (were the items are scrolled up and down but not moved/held to the point where the finger is) but this is the opposite to what I want.

Any help seriously appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while and I don't know a way around it.

Thanks a lot,

Dan

Comment: Are you using the Telerik DragDrop Manager (http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/drag-drop.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the Surface SDK. (If not, why not?)
Then this is a great resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727837.aspx

edit: Rereading your question I saw you used a Touch-overlay. Is it right that these do not trigger the Windows 7 touch events, but merely simulate a mouse? If so, then I'm a little curious as to why drag-and-drop with this does not work as with a regular mouse.

edit2:

So what you need to do is to add two listeners in the datatemplate; PreviewTouchDown and PreviewTouchMove.

This is what I use to start a Drag operation with mouse, but it should work with touch as well, with some modifications.

```
private void TreePreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    _checkDragDrop = true;
}
private void TempTreeMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        var diff = _startPoint - mousePos;
        if (_checkDragDrop)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance || Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {
                _checkDragDrop = false;
                .
                .
                .
                DragDropEffects val = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(DragSourceList, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You probably cannot use the Telerik class with this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - seem to be the only person so far who has a clue. Right, as of yesterday I have switched to the surface SDK. But this means re-writing the whole drag and drop behaviour classes from scratch so that it can interact with a telerik radscheduleview I also have. And it's very tricky. My preference is to get the touch drag and drop feature working on this listbox.

No the multi-touch overlay I'm currently using triggers touch events, it doesn't simulate a mouse as such.

Comment: It's possible to do that. Do you know if the Touch overlay generates touch events, or if it's strictly mouse pointer events?

Comment: It's touch events. At the moment my code is very similar to the code listed in this article: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/dragdropmanager_-howto-drag-between-radscheduleview-and-listbox.html
On my listbox I have wired up the drag drop class that I've defined (same in the above article) but touching the listbox will not fire the necessary events in this class (were a mouse will), but instead fires events such as: private void listBox1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)

Thanks again for your response, really appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: That's probably because the Telerik class is not designed for Touch. What you need to do is to initiate the touch event yourself. I'll edit the answer with some code I think should work. (I don't have a touchscreen right here, but I'll test it when I come home from work)

Comment: To be honest the problem is with a standard wpf listbox. I mentioned telerik control because that's the target, and to code the drag drop for this (between listbox and radscheduleview) it's complicated, so I sort of need to tie in the touch events with the mouse events. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The code you've just posted is for a mouse - and then you went on to even comment and say 'you probably cannot use the telerik class with this.' Forget it. Noone helps out on this site if it's a bit of a tricky one - and the only reason you've responded is cuz I've put my whole rep on it.

Comment: Relax. Read the paragraph above the code: It's what I use to start a drag operation with a mouse, and will probably work with touch with a few modifications. These modifications are something like changing MouseButtonEventArgs to the relevant touch event. And I said probably cannot use the telerik, because I don't know how to use it. (Not that you mentioned you needed to use the Telerik class in the question, mind you). But I guess that you could just call OnDragInitialize or something akin to that instead of DragDrop.DoDragDrop. Since I haven't used Telerik, I can't say for sure.